# Java - Adicionar informações no arquivo XML com JDom

Tags: java, xml, jdom

Nesse código um arquivo xml é criado e um elemento é inserido:

```
comentarios = new Element("comentarios");
    myDocument = new Document(comentarios);
    comentario = new Element("comentario");
    comentario.setAttribute("id", "123");

    Element nome = new Element("nome");
    nome.setText("Otavio");
    Element tempo = new Element("tempo");
    tempo.setText("0.00");
    Element conteudo = new Element("conteudo");
    conteudo.setText("Teste de Comentário");

    comentario.addContent(nome);
    comentario.addContent(tempo);
    comentario.addContent(conteudo);

    comentarios.addContent(comentario);

    XMLOutputter xout = new XMLOutputter();
    try {
        xout.output(myDocument, System.out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        FileWriter arquivo = new FileWriter(new File("c:/xml.xml"));
        xout.output(myDocument, arquivo);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

O código atual sobreescreve o conteúdo original do arquivo, criando um arquivo novo.

**Como fazer para se rodar o arquivo 10 vezes, o arquivo tem que conter 10 dados nele, adicionando um novo elemento ao final do arquivo?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro terá que ler o arquivo antes de adicionar os novos comentários:

```
private static Document lerArquivo(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, JDOMException, IOException{
    Document doc = null;
    Element raiz = null;
    File xmlFile = new File(path);
if(xmlFile.exists()) {
    //ler arquivo se encontrado
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(xmlFile);
    SAXBuilder sb = new SAXBuilder();
    doc = sb.build(fis);
    fis.close();
} else {
    //cria arquivo se não existir
    doc = new Document();
    raiz = new Element("comentarios");
    }
return doc;
}
```

Depois terá que usar o elemento raíz para adicionar os novos comentários:

```
final String PATH = "C:\\xml.xml";
Document myDocument = lerArquivo(PATH);
Element comentarios = myDocument.getRootElement();
Element comentario = new Element("comentario");
```

O exemplo completo:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;

public class JDOMExemplo{
    final String PATH="C:\\xml.xml";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Document myDocument = lerArquivo(PATH);
    Element comentarios = myDocument.getRootElement();
    Element comentario = new Element("comentario");
    comentario.setAttribute("id", "123");

    Element nome = new Element("nome");
    nome.setText("Otavio");
    Element tempo = new Element("tempo");
    tempo.setText("0.00");
    Element conteudo = new Element("conteudo");
    conteudo.setText("Teste de Comentário");

    comentario.addContent(nome);
    comentario.addContent(tempo);
    comentario.addContent(conteudo);
    comentarios.addContent(comentario);


    XMLOutputter xout = new XMLOutputter();
    try {
        xout.output(myDocument, System.out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        FileWriter arquivo = new FileWriter(new File(PATH));
        xout.output(myDocument, arquivo);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    private static Document lerArquivo(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, JDOMException, IOException{
        Document doc = null;
        Element raiz = null;
        File xmlFile = new File(path);
    if(xmlFile.exists()) {
        // try to load document from xml file if it exist
        // create a file input stream
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(xmlFile);
        SAXBuilder sb = new SAXBuilder();
        doc = sb.build(fis);
        raiz = doc.getRootElement();
        fis.close();
    } else {
        // if it does not exist create a new document and new root
        doc = new Document();
        raiz = new Element("comentarios");
        }
    return doc;
    }

}
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, exatamente isso que eu precisava